# Plotting Time Series with call to Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, time-series, data-acquisition

I am trying to plot stocks showing some of the local maxima. As an exercise I first tried to load Apple's stock data from Wolfram Alpha with the following code:

```
appledata =TimeSeries[WolframAlpha["AAPL", {{"History", 1}, "ComputableData"}][[1]]];
  Show[DateListPlot[appledata],DateListPlot[FindPeaks[TimeSeriesResample[appledata], 12], 
  Joined -> False,PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.03], Red]]]
```

However, I am returning the following errors:

```
DateListPlot::ldata: TimeSeries[NotAvailable] is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. >>
FindPeaks::arg: The argument TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[NotAvailable]] at position 1 is not a consistent list of real values. >>
DateListPlot::ldata: FindPeaks[TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[NotAvailable]],12] is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. >>
Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[DateListPlot[TimeSeries[NotAvailable]],DateListPlot[FindPeaks[TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[NotAvailable]],12],Joined->False,PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[0.03],\!\(\*GraphicsBox[{{GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{0, 0}]},{GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{1, -1}]},{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RectangleBox[{0, -1}, {2, 1}]}},AspectRatio->1,Frame->True,FrameStyle-RGBColor[0.6666666666666666, 0., 0.],FrameTicks->None,ImageSize->{Automatic, 10.8},PlotRangePadding->None]\)]]]. >>
```

I'd like to move beyond just searching stocks such as Apple and be able to search tickers, maybe something like https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LENP_enUS562US562&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ugaz&safe=off

Comment: Before stacking all the functions just try to get the W|A call to return something useful on its own. Financial data is obtained through Yahoo finance (well, at least `FinancialData` does that) and the results can be less than stable. Sometimes the same call that worked 5 minutes ago doesn't work now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling Wolfram|Alpha is not generally an efficient way to retrieve bulk data; where possible, it is better to use a built in data function.

Part of the problem is figuring out what to submit to Wolfram|Alpha. In the code you supplied, the issue begins with Wolfram|Alpha returning `Missing[NotAvailable]`. `WolframAlpha["AAPL history",{{"HistoryDaily:Close:FinancialData",1},"ComputableData"}]` worked for me, however.

In this case it is easier to use `FinancialData`, which at least has a documented syntax. So:

```
FinancialData["UGAZ","High",{{2000,1,1},DateList@Now}];
%//TimeSeries;
Show[
  DateListPlot[%],
  DateListPlot[
    FindPeaks[TimeSeriesResample[%],12],
    Joined->False,PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[0.03],Red]]]
```

[image]